# How to fill a font with an image in Inkscape

Tags: layers, inkscape

I have written a word using a fat font like Impact, and I have an image of roses.

Instead of adding a color to this word, I want to "color" it in Inkscape using my roses image.

Comment: I don't use Inkscape so I'm not well suited to answer, but try searching for "clipping mask" - that's what you're trying to do. To do it with text you'll have to do the Inkscape equivalent of Illustrator's "Create Outlines," and you might have to do Illustrator's equivalent of making a compound path out of those outlines. Not sure. Hope that points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

First, add an image by using `File -> Import`. Then, select the image and select `Object -> Pattern -> Objects to Pattern`. Now, you can select an object and set the fill color to pattern. There is a list with different patterns, for example, `Stripes 1:1`. The topmost pattern will be called something like `pattern5448` or a similar name and is the pattern that was generated from the image.

Comment: This is useful although how do you get more control over the location of the "pattern" image within the text?

Comment: I see how to move the pattern.  You select the node tool (F2 edit paths by nodes) then click on the text.  Then on the original image that is the source for the pattern (which is somewhere on your canvas) a small square white box will appear which you can manipulate to adjust the pattern